# php $_GET and undefined index P

Tags: php

i have problem to run my script on a different PHP Server, on my old server the following code appears to work fine - even when p parameter is declared.

```
<?php
$ACCESSKEY="demo";
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

if($_GET['p']==$ACCESSKEY){
  // this is the workaround for file_get_contents(...)
  require_once (dirname(__FILE__).'/PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3/Compat/Function/file_get_contents.php');
  $data = php_compat_file_get_contents('php://input');

  $filename = $_GET['filename'];
  if (file_put_contents($filename,$data)) {
    if (filesize($filename) != 0) {
      echo "Upload success";
    } else {
      header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
      echo "bad request";
    }
  } else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    echo "failed.";
  }
} else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
  echo "Access denied";    
}

?>
```

and the error like this :

```
Notice: Undefined index: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\index.php on line 5
```

How do I fix this? thanks

Comment: Show us the URL you're calling this with.

Comment: im using android for testing demo

Comment: So? You're still calling a URL, right?

Comment: yes, for upload images using PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3

Comment: Then show us the URL . That is where you define `p`, correct?

Comment: i try in my hosting too like this : [30-Jun-2020 12:19:56 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: p in /home/pusatku/public_html/image/upuser_images/save.php on line 5

Comment: Do you have a portion of the URL that looks like `p=some_value`?

Comment: Change `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST`

Comment: i did try using if($_REQUEST['p']==$ACCESSKEY){ the answer is same

Comment: Then you are not setting `p` in any call. Add a `print_r($_REQUEST);` to the top of the PHP script to see what you're receiving.

Comment: This managed to write the name of the image only, but the photo was not uploaded successfully, before the new php version, this worked fine, did it matter?

Comment: It shouldn't matter.

Comment: I just put photos into mysqli via Android, then image going to hosting using PHP_Compat

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to test your app - no one here will. From what I see `p` is not defined in the URL you provided.